# Cut off part of element's content

Tags: html, css, mask

Is it possible to cut off part of div#outer in shape of div#inner? I want to achieve something like this:

[image]

Comment: `background:transparent;` ?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: background:transparent will only show the outer box's background, not through it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it just for a background image to show through the hole, then you can use the same image for the background of the `#inner` div and set its [`background-attachment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-attachment) to `fixed`

Something like

```
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner">div#inner</div>
  div#outer
<div>
```

and

```
body{background:url('someimage') 0 0 no-repeat;}

#inner{
  background:url('someimage') 0 0 no-repeat fixed;
}
```

Demo at http://codepen.io/gpetrioli/pen/GsBbd
(*contains some javascript to move the `div` around, just click and drag*)

Comment: That's exactly what I've been looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mask-image` with an image of the shape you need to cut out, for example:

```
mask-image: url(mask-image.png);
```

However I'm not sure how it works with IE. [Check here for more details on mask-image property](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/);

Comment: The background image for your `#outer` div can't be found, so it's not showing anything.

Comment: For me it's showing up. Please try again, I've just updated images.

Comment: Thanks you. It's solved my problem but I marked Gaby's answer because his solution works on more browsers (fow now). +1.

Answer (score 0):

Try using pseudo elements to attach a transparent element to its parent, with a large border that gives the impression of having a hole:

```
#outer {
    background:red;
    width:400px;
    margin-left: 60px;
    height:100px;
    position:relative;
}
#inner {
    position:absolute;
    right:-150px;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    width:150px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#inner:after {
    content:"";
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    display:block;
    border:red 50px solid;
    position: absolute;
    top:-20px;
    left:0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PMSdG/3/

Comment: Good answer! Much nicer than mine, +1.

Comment: Unfortunately, this answer is not resolving my problem. What if I would want to have circle in middle of div?

Comment: if you want a circle in there, you can add a border-radius: http://jsfiddle.net/PMSdG/2/